# How do I follow URL redirection?

Tags: ruby, redirect, web-scraping

I have a URL and I need to retrieve the URL it redirects to (the number of redirections is arbitrary).

One real example I'm working on is:

```
https://www.google.com/url?q=http://m.zynga.com/about/privacy-center/privacy-policy&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNESJyXBeZenALhKWb52N1vHouAd5Q
```

which will eventually redirect to:

```
http://company.zynga.com/privacy/policy
```

which is the URL I'm interested in.

I tried with `open-uri` as follows:

```
privacy_url = "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://m.zynga.com/about/privacy-center/privacy-policy&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNESJyXBeZenALhKWb52N1vHouAd5Q"
final_url = nil
open(privacy_url) do |h|
  puts "Redirecting to #{h.base_uri}"
    final_url = h.base_uri
end
```

but I keep getting the original URL back, meaning that `final_url` is equal to `privacy_url`.

Is there any way to follow this kind of redirection and programmatically access the resulting URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it, using the Mechanize gem. They key is to enable the `follow_meta_refresh` options, which is disabled by default.

Here's how

```
require 'mechanize'

browser = Mechanize.new
browser.follow_meta_refresh = true

start_url = "https://www.google.com/url?q=http://m.zynga.com/about/privacy-center/privacy-policy&sa=D&usg=AFQjCNESJyXBeZenALhKWb52N1vHouAd5Q"
final_url = nil
browser.get(start_url) do |page|
    final_url = page.uri.to_s
end
puts final_url # => http://company.zynga.com/privacy/policy
```